# What's the right way to separate the Resource Server and the Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

Using spring-security-oauth2 to secure my resources against a SSO endpoint that can act as an authorization server. I'm a bit confused when the documentation states:

> The provider role in OAuth 2.0 is actually split between Authorization Service and Resource Service, and while these sometimes reside in the same application, with Spring Security OAuth you have the option to split them across two applications, and also to have multiple Resource Services that share an Authorization Service.

But I don't think I have found an example of this happening. In sparklr/tonr the authorization server and the resource server reside in the same application. The only example I've seen from searching is [this spring-servlet.xml](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/samples/api/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml), which requires [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/identity/uaa/oauth/RemoteTokenServices.java) custom implementation of `ResourceServerTokenServices` to work.

I'd like to avoid writing a custom implementation of `ResourceServerTokenServices` if at all possible. Is there another way to support an external authorization server in a resource server? Something along the lines of:

```
<bean class="com.example.ExternalAuthorizationServerTokenServices" 
    p:remote-url="https://my-oauth-compatible-sso.com" 
    p:token-endpoint="/oauth/access_token" 
    p:authorize-endpoint="/oauth/authorize" />
```

Is this possible?

*EDIT: I'll add that as a workaround (or maybe this is the intended solution) I'm using a jdbc token store and relying on the fact that both servers happen to have access to that database.

Comment: How is the result looking? I'm starting to face the same issue & any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The result is exactly what I'm looking for. As long as you specify a `JdbcTokenStore` pointed to the same `DataSource` for both the resource server and the authorization server it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I have separated the auth and the resource servers. The test cases are not complete though. You can find it here https://github.com/nareshbafna/oauth2

Comment: I think you should define another authorization server only if you are authentication user via let's say facebook or google

Comment: I am also looking for the right way to split authorization server and resource server though the documentation isn't covers everything about it. if anyone having any example or source will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate open resources and protected resources in the spring-security.xml

Pattern /api/** will be protected and other resources will be open.

```
<!-- Protected resources -->
    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never" use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <!-- <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/> -->
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

Answer (score 0):

for someone that might be interested there is as well another example for separating the authentication server and resources server found here: https://github.com/sharmaritesh/spring-angularjs-oauth2-sample