# Separate Resource and Authorization Server without shared data source

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am interested in implementing separate resource and authorization servers. Understand from [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/oauth/114319-separate-resource-server-and-authorization-server?p=594256#post594256), that for this to work, "Either the tokens have to be decodable locally by the resource server or it has to share storage with the auth server." After almost 2.5 years, I hope that the resource server can resolve a token into a Principal without sharing a data source with the authorization server. As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613301/whats-the-right-way-to-separate-the-resource-server-and-the-authorization-serve) question, is [RemoteTokenServices](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/samples/api/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml) the only means to achieve this? If so what should be the response of "/check_token"?

Comment: It also makes me wonder. And it seems to me that there should be a method to encrypt the token on auth server and then decrypt it on the resource server similar to how certs are working that is containing expiration date, domain etc... Unless I get wrong about whole oauth2 thing.

Comment: Hope this can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669736/microservices-and-spring-security-oauth2/26773707#26773707

Answer (score 3):

`RemoteTokenServices` is not the only way (but with a bit of cacheing thrown in it can be a perfectly good solution), nor was it 2.5 years ago. The other option supported out of the box is JWT tokens (e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/jwt).