# Microservices and Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I already have a OAuth2 authorization server running in another project. Now I would need to secure several simple spring-boot rest-servers with OAuth2. But I'm finding the [Spring documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) really really limited when it comes to separating Authorization and Resource servers.

I've also found several questions where [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778134/spring-oauth2-resource-and-authorization-servers) has been "Well they can be different boxes as long as they share the same tokenStore datasource". Can this really be true? How could this ever work for microservices? It would seem like a really odd thing that every rest service would need to implement it's own OAuth authorization server.

So how do I setup Oauth2.0 security for spring-boot rest-endpoints that refer to a remote oauth authorization server (possibly not even written with Spring)?

There's this thing called [RemoteTokenServices](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.html) that seems promising but it's not really documented at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While configuring your auh server::

Create a new clientDetails in `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` for resource server. which will be used to configure `RemoteTokenService`.

Configure Spring Security OAuth2 in your resource server:

Create a class which is annotate with `@EnableWebSecurity` ,`@Configuration` and extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class ResourceConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  // methods        
}
```

Create a method with @Bean annotated which will return instance of `TokenService`, which will be used to create `AuthenticationManager`.

In this method create an instance of `RemoteTokenService` and set clientId, client_secret , checkTokenEndpointUrl and `DefaultAccessTokenConverterWithClientRoles` (this class is our implementation to get **client_authority** while authenticating **accessToken** in OAuth2 server.)

```
@Bean
public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService() {
    RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setClientId("resource_id");
    tokenServices.setClientSecret("resource_secret");
    tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://<server-url>: <port>/oauth/check_token");
    return tokenServices;
}
```

Override `authenticationManagerBean()` method and annotate it with `@Bean` and return an instance of `OAuth2AuthenticationManager` with `TokenService` injected.

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
    authenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenService());
    return authenticationManager;
}
```

Create a class annotated with `@EnableResourceServer` , `@Configuration` and extend  `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  // Mehotds
}
```

Override Configure methods form the super class to configure resource server.
Different configurer to configure Resource server.

**ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer** : to configure Resource_id.

**HttpSecurity** : This will configure security filter to tell it that user requires authentication for protected URLs (APIs).

```
@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("resource_id");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
     .and()
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    // @formatter:on
}
```

`.antMatcher("/**").authenticated()` this line will secure every api url of your resource server.
`.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`  will not create session.

PS:: If any thing is wrong then tell me.

Comment: is this setup tested in a real app? Most of it looks the same as what I'm doing in my project. However, I'm having troubles with the stateless configuration. Something is being lost between the login and authorization pages. I believe that the OAuth2 implementation doesn't support a stateless setup because the only implementation of the RequestCache interface needs a http session for storing request information (HttpSessionRequestCache). A stateless strategy would store this request data back in the response (maybe in a cookie), so any other replica can go on with the authorization

Answer (score 3):

It's not really true that both have to share the same database, provided the resource server has some way of validating that the access token is genuine (was issued by the authorizations server) and also some way of decoding it (it may need to know what scopes it grants, for example). The OAuth2 spec doesn't say anything about how this is to be achieved.

If the resource is in the same process as the authorization server, then sharing the data is an easy option. Otherwise, it needs some way of translating the token. If the token is just an opaque string of random bytes, then obviously it has to exchange it for the real information. This is what `RemoteTokenServices` does. The authorization server exposes a `/check_token` endpoint to allow the tokens to be decoded.

An alternative is to actually encode the info in the token and have the authorization server digitally sign it. The resource server can then decode and validate the token itself as long as it understand the format.

I'd recommend you look at the Cloudfoundry [UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) which provides an authorization server out of the box which is implemented using signed JWT tokens (it also exposes the `/check_token` endpoint). The [Tokens overview](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-Tokens.md) and the [API docs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst) are probably a good starting point.

Comment: `tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://<server-url>: <port>/oauth/check_token");`

Is there anyway to avoid a hardcoded url ?
I want either 
call directly to any one instance of auth server (runtime url fetch from registry server)
OR
check token from redis. (Using redis token store in auth)

Is anyone of this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

A working sample of `RemoteTokenService` can be found [here](https://github.com/sharmaritesh/spring-angularjs-oauth2-sample).

For more details about `check_token` api, you can refer `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint.java`

On the resource server end, `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` validates OAuth2 token by calling `OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` method which makes the call to `RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication()` to validate the token from the Auth Server.